# Question on XML / Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml

I am very new for XML, please help me for below XML. 
At line 4, Extra content at the end of the document error message is appeared.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE fda-regional:fda-regional SYSTEM "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/static/eCTD/us-regional-v3-3.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/static/eCTD/us-regional.xsl"?>
<fda-regional:fda-regional dtd-version=”3.3” xml:lang=”text” xmlns:fda-regional=”http://www.ich.org/fda” xmlns:xlink=”http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink”>
 <admin>
  <applicant-info>
   <id>123456789</id>
  </applicant-info>
  <application-set> 
   ...
  </application-set>
 </admin>
 <m1-regional>
 </m1-regional>
 <m1-administrative-information-and-prescribing-information>
  ...
 </m1-administrative-information-and-prescribing-information>
</fda-regional:fda-regional>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you copy/pasted this from somewhere with different character set and the character for double-quote is incorrect.  Delete all the double-quotes and re-enter them as below for this line:

```
<fda-regional:fda-regional dtd-version="3.3" xml:lang="text" xmlns:fda-regional="http://www.ich.org/fda" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink">
```

Comment: The root cause is more likely that you typed the XML in a text editor with "smart quotes" enabled. Editors that try to be smart are a curse.

Comment: Yes, one of the reason of the problem is " ". However I have only notepad++ program for XML. would you kindly recommend free XML editor ?

Comment: try the program xmlpad